# How to add text to a MongoDB count query

Tags: mongodb, count

I'm trying to get a text output added to  query to count the number of employed personnel in a DB. I'm using income exists and an indicator that personnel is employed.

My input is

```
db.collection.countDocuments({income{$exists:true)}, {as: {"Number Employed:"}})
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The `countDocuments` function returns a number, not a document.  The second argument is an options object, not a projection.  The [valid options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db-collection-countdocuments) are `limit`, `skip`, `hint`, and `maxTimeMS`.

If you need to return a document with a specific field name, use aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {income{$exists:true}}},
    {$count: "Number Employed"}
])
```